# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function jquery javascript

Tags: jquery

i got an unexpected error when using jquery.I want to open modal if condition is true. All logic goes right but modal is not opening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = "{{ hours_dict.direct_hours_percent }}";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#export_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ( a > 52 ){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#exampleModalCenter3').modal({'show': true});
    }
  });

$('#finalize_hours').click(function(){
  $('#export_form').submit();
  });
});

</script>
```

`<input type="submit" id="finalize_hours" class="btn btn-primary" value="finalize hours">`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Check your browser network log and see how many times jquery is being loaded.

Comment: @Taplar   2 times

Comment: So there's your problem.  The second time jquery loads is most likely after you have imported bootstrap, so the jQuery object is recreated, without the bootstrap methods on it.  You should only be importing jQuery once.

Comment: @Taplar, first i load jquery then javascript's bootstrap.

Comment: Right, and then if jQuery is loaded a second time, (repeat my previous comment)

Comment: @Taplar, yes i import jquery once.

Comment: You said the network console showed it was imported 2 times.

Comment: yes console shows 2 times jquery runs, but i import it only once so where is the issue.

Comment: No clue. If you are not explicitly doing that, then something on your site is injecting it.  You need to figure out where and how that is happening.

Comment: any idea, how can i convert this same logic in core javascript?

Comment: That is a much different and much larger question.  And is avoiding the actual problem.